# LXC-Routing between containers

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx, bridge, lxc

I have a pretty default lxc-setup with one host and several containers. One container *webfrontend* is getting all host-traffic on ports 80 and 443 via DNATing the ports. An nginx on *webfrontend* decides via vhosts, which container *webappX* should get the request and proxies the request through to the webappX' private ip:

```
host:443 <--prerouting--> webfrontend:443 <--nginx--> webappX-private:80

-A PREROUTING -d 80.x.x.x/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.100:443
```

- Host (public): 80.x.x.x
- webfrontend (lxcbr0): 10.0.3.100
- webappX (lxcbr0): 10.0.3.200
- webappY (lxcbr0): 10.0.3.201
- ...

This works fine and allows a central point for letsencrypt-certificates, etc.

However, when webappX needs to access webappY, the connection is refused and the webfrontend never sees the request. I can access webappY on the private ip (from webappX), but I cannot access webappY-public (aka the webfrontend):

```
root@webappX:~# curl -I http://10.0.3.201
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]

root@webappX:~# curl -I http://webappY.example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to webappY.example.com port 80: Connection refused

root@webappX:~# nslookup webappY.example.com
[...]
Name: webappY.example.com
Address: 80.x.x.x
```

Forwarding between the containers are given:

```
*filter
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

So far, I've tried setting POSTROUTING-rules and OUTPUT-rules on eth0 and lo without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you want is NAT hairpinning. You are not hitting your `DNAT` rules, mainly because the traffic comes from another interface than `eth0`. However, I’m not sure that’s all.

Comment: @DanielB devil in the details... that did it. Could you post that as an answer? I'll add the iptables-rule to the answer and award the reputation. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is so called [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (aka NAT loopback, NAT reflection):

> NAT loopback, [...] is a feature in many consumer routers which permits the access of a service via the public IP address from inside the local network.

Why is it not working? The IPTables DNAT rule you provided in your question specifies an incoming interface this rule should apply to: `-i eth0`. Your traffic isn’t coming from `eth0` however, but some virtual network interface or whatever. Just removing this restriction to `eth0` may be sufficient to make it work.

Alternatively, a separate rule could be added to `lxcbr0`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lxcbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 \
    --destination 80.x.x.x -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.100:443
```